# Cuda application segfaulting at __cudaUnregisterFatBinary() (NVCC 10.2) versus __cudaUnregisterFatBinary() (NVCC 10.0)

Tags: cuda, nvidia, nvcc

Is there a big difference in terms of the implementation between `__cudaUnregisterFatBinary()` (NVCC 10.2) and  `__cudaUnregisterFatBinary()` (NVCC 10.0).

My program segfaults at `__cudaUnregisterFatBinary()` (NVCC 10.2) inside libcudart.so, and works just fine with the 10.0 version.
I am calling the `cudaUnregisterFatBinary()` and `cudaRegisterFatBinary()` from different .cpp files (I am doing some function interposition - aka wrapping CUDA calls).
And also I am making sure to pass the correct arguments (void **fatCubinHandle).
Any thoughts if there's a huge difference between the two nvcc version that might make my app fail!

The only solution I have left is to disable this call, once inside the cudaUnregisterFatBinary() wrapper, I just exit before calling the real cudart implementation! Could that affect the GPU device memory?

Comment: "And also I am making sure to pass the correct arguments" -- how do you know you are passing the correct arguments when that is an undocumented, internal only API which is not intended to ever be called in user code?

Comment: 1- registering: fatCubinHandle = __cudaRegisterFatBinary(fatCubin);
2-Unregistering __cudaUnregisterFatBinary(fatCubinHandle);
This is how it is used (You can check the runtime code inside crt/host_runtime.h)! 
Also, this is just function interposition and I have a shared library of wrapper functions. So the user code never calls directly these functions ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe difference between both versions is the that cuda 10.2 requires the cudaRegisterFatBinaryEnd right after calling cudaRegisterFatBinary, whereas cuda 10.0 does not require this call!!!